# Leer archivos de disco con Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Hola alguien sabe como leer archivos almacenados en disco de maquina cliente desde postgresql, ademas si es posible filtrar la busqueda por la extension del archivo. Por ejemplo .SQL

en sql server usaba `EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'dir /b "C:\Folder_Scripts\*.sql"'` para en postgresql no estoy encontrando la manera. Gracias.

Comment: ¿En cual sistema operativo está instalado PostgreSQL? ¿Windows también, u otro?

Comment: El cliente tiene windows y el servidor Linux @sstan

Comment: Hmm, debe haber una confusión. Con SQL Server, `xp_cmdshell` te permitía acceder a los archivos del servidor, no del cliente. Tal vez la diferencia no fue clara si ambos estaban en la misma máquina. Pero similarmente, en PostgreSQL, sería posible acceder a los archivos del servidor usando funciones escritas en Perl o Python, o usando una extensión como [pl/sh](https://github.com/petere/plsh). Pero no veo cómo ni porqué usarías a PostgreSQL para acceder archivos del lado cliente.

Comment: @sstan Tenes razon con lo de leer los archivos desde el servidor en sql server. En cuanto a Postgresql mi idea radica al momento de actualizar la versión de mi aplicación, a menudo la version contiene mas de 50 store procedure, por eso la idea que tengo es leer los nombres de los sp que vienen en la version, verificar de que existan en la base y de ser asi los renombro y corro los nuevos, caso contrario simplemente lo corro.

Answer (score 0):

Desde bash ejecuta

```
cat *.sql | psql [parámetros]
```

Esto supone que la carpeta activa es en donde están los archivos sql.

Dependiendo de cómo esté configurado tu acceso a postgres (contraseña, usuario del sistema, nombre de la base de datos etc...) tendrás que agregar los *parámetros* de conexión (los mismos que utilizas para iniciar `psql`).